# Facebook Integration Responds with Wrong user id compared to Facebook API Explorer

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, integration, facebook

Integrating Facebook And Salesforce. 
GET Call to facebook With following fields.

```
me?fields=id,name,picture
```

**Apex Programatically called for profile**

```
{
"id" : "1147023234234323",
"name" : "XXXXXXXXX",
"picture" : {
    "data" : {
        "is_silhouette" : false,
        "url" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13658929_1039496126324432434_8074761334243243213_n.jpg?oh=98bf237b2eb03fbe8f8d234234tegfdoe=58DC034702"
    }
 }
}
```

**Facebook Explorer Call.**

```
{
 "id": "3453455234244444",
 "name": "XXXXXXXX",
 "picture": {
  "data": {
  "is_silhouette": false,
  "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13658929_1039496126324432434_8074761334243243213_n.jpg?oh=98bf237b2eb03fbe8f8d234234tegfdoe=58DC034702"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Provides Application wise ID for every resource. Application need to be permitted by user. The IDs will be within that scope.

Facebook Graph API explorer is a different context. while **Application** is Different Context than **facebook API EXPLORER**  Thats why Both are different.

Answer (score 0):

Natavar,

Is there a mechanism we can get one user I'd and query for another..since the customer owns both Facebook page and it's messenger bot..which has 2 different t ID..any luck?